# Converting Drawing.Image into Byte[]

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a code like this:

```
 using (var image = Image.FromFile(imagePath))
                {
                    image.Save(Path.ChangeExtension(imagePath, "jpg"), ImageFormat.Jpeg);                        
                }
```

This converts the given image file into different format and saves it onto the HDD.

How can I convert the image into JPG, but instead of saving it, I want to put it into a byte[] variable.
Something like:

```
byte[] img = image.ByteArray(Path.ChangeExtension(imagePath, "jpg"), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Is this possible to do, without saving the image onto the HDD first and then loading it into byte array from a file?

Comment: Actually it is not a duplicate bcs in the other question answer there was a System.Drawing assembly based method while in .NET Core there is no equivalent functionality. Therefore code from question and linked answer simply will fail with exception.